# Стиль директивы #include

Tags: c++, best-practice

Сегодня был спор с коллегами. Предметом стала такая строка:

```
#include "../second_subproject/header.h"
```

в проекте со следующей структурой:

- project

  - first_subproject
  - second_subproject
  - third_subproject
  - ...

Они придерживались точки зрения, что first_subproject, second_subproject, third_subproject, etc. должны быть указаны как include directories при помощи параметров проекта, а `include` примет следующий вид:

```
#include "header.h"
```

Я же утверждал, что ничего криминального в первом варианте нет, и он даже более наглядный(правда позже выяснил, что ".." это непереносимо).

Таким образом есть 3 варианта:

```
    #include "../second_subproject/header.h"

    // ../first_subproject добавлен как include diectory
    // ../second_subproject добавлен как include diectory
    // ../third_subproject добавлен как include diectory
    #include "header.h"

    // .. добавлен как include diectory
    #include "second_subproject/header.h"
```

Какой вариант считается хорошим тоном, какой плохим? Плюсы/минусы? Может про это написано в каких-нибудь стайлгайдах(мозила, гну, гугл, майкрософт и т.п.) или книгах?

Comment: По-моему тут следует сначала определиться: являются ли "субпроекты" `first_subproject`, `second_subproject` и т.д.  самостоятельными. Если да (т.е. могут использоваться вместе или по отдельности в разном составе), то следует указать папку с инклюдами, и писать `#include <header.h>`. Если нет (т.е. это просто куски одного и того же поекта, разложенные по папкам), то тогда писать относительный путь `#include "../second_subproject/header.h"`

Comment: @VTT В случае независимых проектов, я бы создал отдельную папку `share_headers` вне всех субпроектов, в нее бы положил все хедеры, которые могут использоваться разными суброектами и эту папку указалбы как инклуд-директорию

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А перекладывать эти хедеры после каждого пула не замучаетесь?

Comment: По возможности я бы стремился к `#include "second_subproject/header.h"` (Каталог, содержащий `second_subproject/` можно делать доступным через -I... в Makefile)